# Exposing field of child object in Spring hateoas

Tags: spring, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

I have two entities defined:

```
@Entity
public class VideoPost {
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY) Long id;
    private String videoTitle;
    private @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "VideoPost_Id") User uploader;
    private boolean isPublished = false;

    //....
}


@Entity
public class User {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) Long id;
    private String userName;
    private Date registrationDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "uploader", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  private List<VideoPost> videoPosts;

    //...

}
```

I have following JSON response to the call to /api/videoposts:

```
"_embedded" : {
    "videoPosts" : [ {
      "videoTitle" : "test video 1",
      "uploadDate" : "2017-06-03T11:44:02.012+0000",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/videoPosts/1"
        },
        "videoPost" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/videoPosts/1"
        },
        "uploader" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/videoPosts/1/uploader"
        }
      }
    }   ]
```

I would like to expose the uploader name inside this response directly. I.e.

```
"uploader" : {
    "userName": theName
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/videoPosts/1/uploader"
}
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using spring-data-rest to provide the HTTP endpoints or have you written your own controller and using `org.springframework.hateoas.Resource` to render the resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) where you can customize you objects the way you want whether you want to show the whole nested attributes or some of them or even hide these nested objects